# Tab indicator no longer at the bottom of AppBarLayout after migrating app to AndroidX. The tab is custom made tab

Tags: android-studio, androidx, android-tablayout, android-appbarlayout

I migrated android app to AndroidX and then I noticed this

[image]

As you can see the tab indicator went up into the AppBarLayout. Here is the code

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        ... // some code here relevant to toolbar
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/custom_tab" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/custom_tab" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/custom_tab"/>

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

The custom layout I created is below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tab_title"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       tools:text="CONTRIBUTIONS"
       style="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab"/>

       <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_number"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tab_title"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       tools:text="1000"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
       style="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab"
       />

       <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
       android:text="@string/open_bracket"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_number"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_number"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_number"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
       style="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab"/>

       <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
       android:text="@string/closing_bracket"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_number"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_number"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_number"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
       style="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

It looks fine in android 22 and below but not android 24 and above. However before this migration to androidx it was fine in all versions i.e the indicator was at bottom of appbarlayout not inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You must set `app:tabIndicatorColor="YOUR_COLOR"` in TabLayout like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/blue">

... // Your TabItems

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

if doesn't work, try to remove `android:layout="@layout/custom_tab"` from TabItems too.

Comment: thanks for your response but I didn't ask how to change the color of tab indicator please read my question well.

Comment: You need to set tab indicator on TabLayout. It seems you are setting tab indicator in android:layout="@layout/custom_tab", that's why it is no longer at the bottom.

Comment: try to put only app:tabIndicator="YOUR_COLOR" too.